# Re-open vim to same line after compiling tex

Tags: vim, tex, pdflatex

I have in my .vimrc:

```
map = :w !pdflatex %
```

to quickly write and compile tex without leaving vim. However, when it has compiled and I get back to vim, I am at the top of the document. Is there a way to have this mapping return me to the line at which I left off? Thanks!

Comment: My vim (7.4) doesn't do this behavior. You may want to disable some of your other mappings and/or plugins to see if this is some kind of conflict. I also suggest making sure you have the latest version of Vim. I would also suggest you change your mapping like so: `nnoremap = :w !pdflatex %<cr>`. The `=` command is pretty handy so you may want to choose another mapping so you don't overshadow it maybe use `<f5>` or use a more useless key like `<space>` or `<leader>`

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I modified my mapping to:

`map = :w<CR>:silent !pdflatex %<CR>:!open %<.pdf<CR> :<CR>`

and that returns me to my place. The only difference there is that it opens the compiled pdf and carriage returns at various places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uncomment this in your vimrc to keep your previous position.

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
if has("autocmd")
    au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif
```

Comment: What are you uncommenting? The if statement is already uncommented?